# C++ compilation error undefined reference to log4cplus and boost

Tags: c++, docker, ubuntu

**Context**

I have pulled code from the concord repo at https://github.com/vmware/concord. I managed to build the docker images fine.
In the documentation at https://concord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment/deployment.html#confguration-file-generator they mention a configuration file generator that is used to generate configuration files which is required to run a concord node using docker run (the command to run the concord node is defined at https://concord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment/deployment.html#concord-nodes). This configuration file generator is a .cpp called conc_genconfig.cpp (available at https://github.com/vmware/concord/blob/master/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp) and requires a .yml as an input. This uses library files from log4cplus and boost. I installed these by looking at the Dockerfile under the builder folder (available at https://github.com/vmware/concord/blob/master/docker/dockerfiles/builder/Dockerfile)

**Problem** 
When I compile conc_genconfig.cpp using the following command:

```
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -LLIBDIR  -I /home/ubuntu/concord/src -I /home/ubuntu/concord-bft/threshsign/include/threshsign conc_genconfig.cpp
```

I get the following output/compilation errors:

```
In file included from conc_genconfig.cpp:23:0:
/home/ubuntu/concord/src/config/configuration_manager.hpp:1547:23: warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
     kPositiveIntLimits({1, INT_MAX});
                       ^
/home/ubuntu/concord/src/config/configuration_manager.hpp:1549:26: warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
     kPositiveUInt16Limits({1, UINT16_MAX});
                          ^
/home/ubuntu/concord/src/config/configuration_manager.hpp:1551:26: warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
     kPositiveUInt64Limits({1, UINT64_MAX});
                          ^
/home/ubuntu/concord/src/config/configuration_manager.hpp:1553:29: warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
     kPositiveULongLongLimits({1, ULLONG_MAX});
                             ^
/home/ubuntu/concord/src/config/configuration_manager.hpp:1554:77: warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
 inline const std::pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long> kUInt16Limits(
                                                                             ^
/home/ubuntu/concord/src/config/configuration_manager.hpp:1556:77: warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
 inline const std::pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long> kUInt32Limits(
                                                                             ^
/home/ubuntu/concord/src/config/configuration_manager.hpp:1558:77: warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
 inline const std::pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long> kUInt64Limits(
                                                                             ^
/home/ubuntu/concord/src/config/configuration_manager.hpp:1560:58: warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
 inline const std::pair<long long, long long> kInt32Limits({INT32_MIN,
                                                          ^
/home/ubuntu/concord/src/config/configuration_manager.hpp:1566:45: warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
     kConcordBFTCommunicationBufferSizeLimits({512, UINT32_MAX});
                                             ^
/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:44: undefined reference to `log4cplus::initialize()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:45: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::getDefaultHierarchy()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:45: undefined reference to `log4cplus::BasicConfigurator::BasicConfigurator(log4cplus::Hierarchy&, bool)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:46: undefined reference to `log4cplus::PropertyConfigurator::configure()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:48: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:54: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::variables_map::variables_map()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:55: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:55: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:55: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:58: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::add_options()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:59: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:63: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:70: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:71: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:85: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::basic_parsed_options<char> const&, boost::program_options::variables_map&, bool)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:92: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::operator<<(std::ostream&, boost::program_options::options_description const&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:95: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::notify(boost::program_options::variables_map&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:97: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:97: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:97: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:100: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:100: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:100: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:108: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:108: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:108: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:114: undefined reference to `concord::config::YAMLConfigurationInput::YAMLConfigurationInput(std::istream&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:116: undefined reference to `concord::config::YAMLConfigurationInput::parseInput()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:129: undefined reference to `concord::config::ConcordConfiguration::ConcordConfiguration()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:130: undefined reference to `concord::config::specifyConfiguration(concord::config::ConcordConfiguration&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:131: undefined reference to `concord::config::ConcordConfiguration::setConfigurationStateLabel(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:134: undefined reference to `concord::config::loadClusterSizeParameters(concord::config::YAMLConfigurationInput&, concord::config::ConcordConfiguration&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:141: undefined reference to `concord::config::instantiateTemplatedConfiguration(concord::config::YAMLConfigurationInput&, concord::config::ConcordConfiguration&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:150: undefined reference to `concord::config::loadConfigurationInputParameters(concord::config::YAMLConfigurationInput&, concord::config::ConcordConfiguration&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:156: undefined reference to `concord::config::ConcordConfiguration::loadAllDefaults(bool, bool)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:158: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:158: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:158: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:164: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:164: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:164: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:167: undefined reference to `concord::config::generateConfigurationKeys(concord::config::ConcordConfiguration&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:168: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:168: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:168: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:177: undefined reference to `concord::config::ConcordConfiguration::generateAll(bool, bool)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:179: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:179: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:179: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:185: undefined reference to `concord::config::ConcordConfiguration::scopeIsInstantiated(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:186: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:186: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:186: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:192: undefined reference to `concord::config::ConcordConfiguration::validateAll(bool, bool)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:194: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:194: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:194: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:199: undefined reference to `concord::config::hasAllParametersRequiredAtConfigurationGeneration(concord::config::ConcordConfiguration&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:200: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:200: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:200: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:205: undefined reference to `concord::config::ConcordConfiguration::scopeSize(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:210: undefined reference to `concord::config::YAMLConfigurationOutput::YAMLConfigurationOutput(std::ostream&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:212: undefined reference to `concord::config::outputConcordNodeConfiguration(concord::config::ConcordConfiguration const&, concord::config::YAMLConfigurationOutput&, unsigned long)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:222: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:222: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:222: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:222: undefined reference to `concord::config::YAMLConfigurationOutput::~YAMLConfigurationOutput()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:231: undefined reference to `concord::config::outputPrincipalLocationsMappingJSON(concord::config::ConcordConfiguration&, std::ostream&)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:241: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:241: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:241: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:129: undefined reference to `concord::config::ConcordConfiguration::~ConcordConfiguration()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:114: undefined reference to `concord::config::YAMLConfigurationInput::~YAMLConfigurationInput()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:48: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::~Logger()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:45: undefined reference to `log4cplus::BasicConfigurator::~BasicConfigurator()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:118: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:118: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:118: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:124: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:124: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:124: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:136: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:136: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:136: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:143: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:143: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:143: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:152: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:152: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:152: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:170: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:170: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:170: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:173: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:173: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:173: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:214: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:214: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:214: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:218: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:218: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:218: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:210: undefined reference to `concord::config::YAMLConfigurationOutput::~YAMLConfigurationOutput()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:233: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::isEnabledFor(int) const'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:233: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss[abi:cxx11]()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:233: undefined reference to `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:129: undefined reference to `concord::config::ConcordConfiguration::~ConcordConfiguration()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:114: undefined reference to `concord::config::YAMLConfigurationInput::~YAMLConfigurationInput()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:48: undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::~Logger()'
/home/ubuntu/concord/tools/conc_genconfig.cpp:45: undefined reference to `log4cplus::BasicConfigurator::~BasicConfigurator()'
/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o: In function `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::value_semantic_codecvt_helper()':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:91: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>'
/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o: In function `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::~value_semantic_codecvt_helper()':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:91: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>'
/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*)':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/parsers.hpp:44: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)'
/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::options(boost::program_options::options_description const&)':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/parsers.hpp:52: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::set_options_description(boost::program_options::options_description const&)'
/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::run()':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/parsers.hpp:108: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::get_canonical_option_prefix()'
/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/parsers.hpp:109: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::run()'
/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o: In function `std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > boost::program_options::to_internal<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/convert.hpp:79: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::to_internal(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool) const'
/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEE[_ZTIN5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEE]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>'
/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o: In function `boost::program_options::variables_map::~variables_map()':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp:146: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::variables_map'
/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char>::name() const':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:22: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg[abi:cxx11]'
/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char>::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&) const':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:184: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Versions and OS**
I am using: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
gcc version: gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
g++ version: g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
libboost version: Version: 1.65.1.0ubuntu1

**Environment variables**
I have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/local/lib. This is where log4cplus libraries have been built.

I apologise if this question is not clear. Please let me know if that is the case so I can improve my question. If anyone can, please add the tag 'concord' to the question.

Comment: The main problem: You need to link the libraries in on your build command line, with something like `-lboost_options -llog4cplus`. I don't think `-LLIBDIR` is doing what you think it's doing, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for run-time library loading, not build-time linking. (Also, it is bad form to rely on it at runtime in general.) The warnings about inline variables could also be trouble, but you can ask a separate question about that if needed.

Comment: Thank you @metal. I tried that but didn't work. Could this possibly be an issue with versions, perhaps?

Comment: In what way did it not work? What were the error messages?

Comment: Well, it said syntax error when I used  lboost_options -llog4cplus in my compilation command. How to exactly place it?

Comment: What are the libraries you want to link to named on disk?

Comment: There are boost libraries at /usr/include/boost/program_options/ and log4cplus libraries at /usr/local/lib. The log output I put in the question says "undefined reference" for methods in these. Then there are compiled files like these in the error output :/tmp/cc2pIDGw.o, if you see the log that I pasted. I am not sure what these are

Comment: What are the names of the library files themselves? Something like: `libboost_options.a`, `liboptions.so.1.63.0` etc. etc.?

Comment: In /usr/local/lib there are : liblog4cplus-2.0.so.3, liblog4cplus.la, liblog4cplus-2.0.so.3.4.4, liblog4cplus.so, liblog4cplusU.a, liblog4cplus.a, liblog4cplusU-2.0.so.3, liblog4cplusU.la. In /usr/include/boost/program_options/ there are: cmdline.hpp  environment_iterator.hpp, option.hpp, positional_options.hpp,version.hpp
config.hpp, eof_iterator.hpp, options_description.hpp, value_semantic.hpp, errors.hpp, parsers.hpp, variables_map.hpp

Comment: So you probably need `-llog4cplus-2.0` or maybe one with a `U` in the name if you need Unicode. If you want to pick the exact file rather than rely on linker rules, you can do something like  `-l:liblog4cplusU-2.0.so.3`. you'll need to do the same with the library for Boost program options, since I don't believe it is a header-only part of Boost.

Comment: Hi @metal I got rid of some of the compilation errors using                                    g++ -Wall -static -L/usr/local/lib -L/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3f85b358c99065ac71090497ca371b8680e40b64d3336d35d6f90ffccc6e58fb/diff/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/include/boost L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -I /home/ubuntu/concord/src -I /home/ubuntu/concord-bft/threshsign/include/threshsign conc_genconfig.cpp -llog4cplus -lpthread -lboost_program_options -lyaml-cpp

Comment: Does any problem remain? Minor point: it's linker errors you were facing, not compile errors. PS, You should not need those complicated paths after `-L` unless you're doing some odd cross-compile. I'd expect it is sufficient to do: `g++ -Wall -static -I /home/ubuntu/concord/src -I /home/ubuntu/concord-bft/threshsign/include/threshsign conc_genconfig.cpp -llog4cplus -lpthread -lboost_program_options -lyaml-cpp`. Maybe you also need `-L/usr/local/lib`, but maybe not.

Comment: Yeah, I do get some errors like 
conc_genconfig.cpp:(.text+0x992): undefined reference to `concord::config::YAMLConfigurationInput::YAMLConfigurationInput(std::istream&)'
conc_genconfig.cpp:(.text+0x9a1): undefined reference to `concord::config::YAMLConfigurationInput::parseInput()'

Perhaps it is a version issue. Thank you so much for your help